# someone/some people

Tags: meaning, pronouns, quantifiers

a. I had to publish those documents so that someone would believe me.

b. I had to publish those documents so that some people would believe me.

I think in (a) nobody believed me before I published those documents.

Is that correct?

And in (b) did anyone believe me before I published those documents?

Is it possible that some people did already believe me and the publication of the documents made some others believe me?

Comment: No, you're not correct. Whether you write ***someone*** or ***some people*** in this context doesn't change the fact of the pragmatically logical implication (that nobody believed you before you published those documents). But neither terms are particularly idiomatic - normally I'd just expect *so **people** would believe me* in such contexts (or ***more people*** if some already believe, ***and*** it's important to communicate that fact).

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I'm missing something . I said in (a) nobody believed me, and you seem to confirm that. Regarding (b) I didn't say anything. I just asked a question. The answer to that question seems to be 'no', which is fine by me. I don't think you're contradicting me. You're saying the answer to my question is 'no'.

Comment: Ah, right. I see what you mean. I should have said *No, that different interpretation for (b) is not possible*. In which case arguably *you are correct* (to suspect that, if indeed you did).

Answer (score 1):

"Someone" can be used to refer to a person that you know but are not naming, for example, "I'm seeing someone" (to mean you are in the beginnings of a relationship with another person).

However, "someone" can also be used to refer to an *unknown* or not yet identified person, for example, "someone has stolen my wallet" (you don't know who), or "can someone help me?" (you are hoping someone will respond, but have no specific person in mind). It can also be used to refer to a speculative, or hypothetical person.

In your example (a) the action was taken without knowing who might believe it, so it is speculative. They can't possibly know that only one person would believe, so the "someone" does not necessarily represent just one person. Many people could come to believe them, but by saying "someone" it suggests that they would be satisfied with just one person as a minimum.

"Some people" is not a plural of "someone". It can only really refer to some *specific* people. For that reason, your example (b) sounds wrong to me. Who are these people?

A better way of saying, in a hopeful way, that more than one person would come to believe it would be:

> I had to publish those documents so that **others** would believe me.

As you said, both of these statements (when written idiomatically) sound like nobody believed them before they took this action.